# How do I restore a wallet with seed?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery

I am running monero.win.x64.v0-10-0-0 on windows 10. I am trying to restore a wallet with a seed but do not know how to do it. When I open monero-wallet-cli after monerorod synchronizes it asks for a wallet name straight away then generates a new wallet. Can someone tell me how I go about restoring my wallet please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to launch `monero-wallet-cli` from the terminal (on Linux and mac OS X) or from the command prompt (on Windows) with the `--restore-deterministic-wallet` flag. Thus:

For Mac and Linux:

`./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet`

Make sure the terminal is opened in the same directory as `monero-wallet-cli` is located in.

On Windows make sure to launch it from the command line. Go to the folder `monero-cli-wallet` is located and make sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files. Subsequently do SHIFT + right click and it will give you an option to "Open command window here". Lastly, type the following command:

`monero-wallet-cli.exe --restore-deterministic-wallet`

For all operating systems it will first ask you for a new wallet name and password. Subsequently, you have to enter the 25 word mnemonic seed. Lastly, enter `refresh` into `monero-wallet-cli`.

P.S. Note that `simplewallet` was renamed to `monero-wallet-cli` in v0.10.0.

Comment: Great, It was not working before because I was not adding the .exe. Thanks a lot.