# How to sweep coins from an existing monero address if you have all the keys?

Tags: address, sweep-transaction

I have a bunch of xmr addresses with all the keys. How can I sweep the coins from these addresses into my own? Which wallet support this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Need to restore each wallet separately and sweep one by one.

[How do I restore a wallet with seed?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/how-do-i-restore-a-wallet-with-seed)

[If I saved my view key and spend key can I recover my wallet if my mnemonic seed is lost?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/55/if-i-saved-my-view-key-and-spend-key-can-i-recover-my-wallet-if-my-mnemonic-seed)